# Trouble installing JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, windows-8

I've been having a really difficult time trying to install JSON and the Ruby development kit to get Rails to work in Windows 8. I believe JSON is getting installed, but to the wrong directory and that is why Ruby can't find it. I believe the problem lies with my PATH variable, or my directories.

When I run this command:

```
gem install json -v '1.8.1'
```

I receive the following output:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.
1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.1/ext/json/ext/ge
nerator/gem_make.out
```

The above output leads me to believe that the problem lies with my PATH but I can't pinpoint what exactly it is.

This line I think is the most important

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.
    1 for inspection.
This leads me to believe JSON is installed, but not in the right directory.

After running gem install, I received this message.

Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Another clue that the problem might be related to the path. If it's temporarily enhancing the path, that means the path wasn't right to begin with.

This is the result of running PATH:

```
C:\Ruby200\bin; C:\Windows\system32; C:Windows\System32\Wbem; 
C:Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\SimplePass; 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared; 
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;
C:\Users********\AppData\Roaming\npm –
```

Here is more information:

```
* Ruby Version - 2.0.0
* Operating System - Windows 8
* Platform - 64bit
* Devkit version - mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe
```

I also ran the following:

```
chdir C:\Ruby200\devkit
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb review
ruby dk.rb install
```

Here is the location of my Ruby directory:

```
C:\Ruby200
```

Here is the location of my devkit inside of my Ruby directory:

C:\Ruby200\devkit
Here are the files and directories located inside the devkit directory:

```
etc (directory)
  >fstab.sample
  >inputrc.default
  >profile
  >termcap
mingw (directory)
  >bin (directory)
  >contrib (directory)
  >include (directory)
  >lib (directory)
  >libexec (directory)
  >licenses (directory)
  >man (directory)
  >manifest (directory)
  >share (directory)
  >x86_64_w64-mingw32 (directory)
  >mingw64env.cmd
postinstall (directory)
  >pi.bat
  >pi.sh
sbin (directory)
  >awk (directory)
devkitvars.bat
devkitvars.ps1
dk.rb
m.ico
msys.bat
msys.ico
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, but as always help will be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have searched every single page in Stack Overflow and still can't find an answer. This is hopeless.

Comment: What's in the log file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780756/cannot-install-json-gem-in-rails-using-windows) ?

```
The devkit installs a C-compiler (and some other stuff) to compile C-written parts.

Install it and try again to install the gem - perhaps with option --platform=ruby
```

and from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906248/error-installing-the-json-gem-on-windows)

```
# Platform specific gems
platforms :ruby do
  gem 'json'
end

platforms :mswin, :mingw do
  gem 'json_pure'
end
```