# Ruby DevKit problems

Tags: ruby, makefile, devkit

I have some troubles with the DevKit installation. Basically, it's not working. I've installed it by the [books](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) but the installation fails the test:

```
gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
```

returns the following error:

```
C:\Ruby 1.9.3-p327\DevKit>gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        "C:/Ruby 1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
checking for random()... no
checking for srandom()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for srand()... yes
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:219: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby 1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/r
discount-1.6.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby 1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdiscount-1.6.8/ex
t/gem_make.out
```

Also [this](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun) is of no use. everything is fine there.

The gem_make.out contains this :

```
"C:/Ruby 1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby.exe" extconf.rb
checking for random()... no
checking for srandom()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for srand()... yes
creating Makefile

make
Makefile:219: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

At this point I am going crazy. I try running just extconf.rb

```
C:\Ruby 1.9.3-p327\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rdiscount-1.6.8\ext>ruby extconf.rb
checking for random()... no
checking for srandom()... no
checking for rand()... yes
checking for srand()... yes
creating Makefile
```

No errors!

My OS is windows 7 x64! There are no other versions of Ruby or DevKit installed on the system and this is the PATH

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Ruby 1.9.3-p327\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\pik;C:\Ruby 1.9.3-p327\DevKit\bin;C:\Ruby 1.9.3-p327\DevKit\mingw\bin
```

Comment: Can you try to install it in a folder without spaces? I remember it solved some of my problems in the past.

Comment: is not working :( same errors changed the paths also

Comment: The books don't mention adding devkit to your path. I recommend removing that, reading more carefully and trying again.

Comment: please refrain from posting demeaning answers. I have added the path because it was recommended somewhere on the rubyinstaller google group. However, in my situation, adding or removing these elements from PATH does not yield different results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be wrong but I think the Ruby installation path is being read as two different arguments, effectively `"C:/Ruby" "1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby.exe"` because the path has not been escaped (is that the right word? Wrapped in quotes basically).

I suggest you take a look at a [similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888061/installing-dm-types-on-windows-win7-x64). I had exactly the same problem as you, and this solution solved it straight-away.

Comment: Thanks man! Solved the problem. I re installed ruby w/o spaces and everything is working now.